# Is there a minimum confidence for celebrity detection in microsoft cognitive services api?

Tags: computer-vision, detection, azure-cognitive-services

All the confidences I've seen for celebrity detection has been very high.  Is there some minimum confidence threshold for which the API will not consider a celebrity present?

Answer (score 0):

The API will return an empty or null `"celebrities"` JSON array if it doesn't recognize a celebrity and will only return a populated `"celebrities"` JSON array if the `"confidence"` level is above `0`.

Here's an examples running 2 pictures of Michael Jackson through the [celebrities and landmarks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#celebrities-landmarks) section in the Computer Vision API page:

**Michael Jackson is recognized and a populated `"celebrities"` JSON array is returned**

[image]

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "people_portrait",
      "score": 0.62109375,
      "detail": {
        "celebrities": [
          {
            "name": "Michael Jackson",
            "faceRectangle": {
              "left": 377,
              "top": 282,
              "width": 381,
              "height": 381
            },
            "confidence": 0.99902832508087158
          }
        ],
        "landmarks": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "adult": null,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "person",
      "confidence": 0.99581664800643921
    }
  ],
  "description": {
    "tags": [
      "person",
      "man",
      "young",
      "standing",
      "looking",
      "front",
      "holding",
      "wearing",
      "shirt",
      "posing",
      "boy",
      "white",
      "smiling",
      "dark",
      "black",
      "table",
      "large",
      "suit",
      "woman",
      "board"
    ],
    "captions": [
      {
        "text": "Michael Jackson posing for the camera",
        "confidence": 0.91584373926593021
      }
    ]
  },
  "requestId": "ac41aa84-9a70-4ffc-8de4-5a662600fc56",
  "metadata": {
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 1000,
    "format": "Jpeg"
  },
  "faces": [
    {
      "age": 31,
      "gender": "Male",
      "faceRectangle": {
        "left": 377,
        "top": 282,
        "width": 381,
        "height": 381
      }
    }
  ],
  "color": {
    "dominantColorForeground": "White",
    "dominantColorBackground": "Black",
    "dominantColors": [
      "Black",
      "White"
    ],
    "accentColor": "B64215",
    "isBWImg": false
  },
  "imageType": {
    "clipArtType": 0,
    "lineDrawingType": 0
  }
}
```

**Michael Jackson is not recognized and an empty `"celebrities"` JSON array is returned**

[image]

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "people_",
      "score": 0.94140625,
      "detail": {
        "celebrities": [],
        "landmarks": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "adult": null,
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "person",
      "confidence": 0.99912232160568237
    },
    {
      "name": "outdoor",
      "confidence": 0.936089813709259
    }
  ],
  "description": {
    "tags": [
      "person",
      "outdoor",
      "man",
      "woman",
      "standing",
      "front",
      "suit",
      "holding",
      "car",
      "wearing",
      "people",
      "couple",
      "posing",
      "young",
      "bus",
      "black",
      "smiling",
      "glasses",
      "umbrella",
      "group",
      "table",
      "city",
      "red",
      "water",
      "street",
      "phone",
      "boat",
      "train"
    ],
    "captions": [
      {
        "text": "a couple of people posing for the camera",
        "confidence": 0.86922603629725859
      }
    ]
  },
  "requestId": "7d57493c-f8b0-468f-8135-17da555d2463",
  "metadata": {
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 1000,
    "format": "Jpeg"
  },
  "faces": [
    {
      "age": 38,
      "gender": "Female",
      "faceRectangle": {
        "left": 400,
        "top": 270,
        "width": 234,
        "height": 234
      }
    }
  ],
  "color": {
    "dominantColorForeground": "Black",
    "dominantColorBackground": "Black",
    "dominantColors": [
      "Black",
      "Grey"
    ],
    "accentColor": "364E5D",
    "isBWImg": false
  },
  "imageType": {
    "clipArtType": 0,
    "lineDrawingType": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, please check my updated answer, I included an example.

Comment: The first image, azure is 99.9% confident that this is michael jackson, the second image azure does not think this is michael jackson... there's no sense of threshold in what you've linked me.  I've run 20k images through the API and have yet to find a celebrity tagged with a lower confidence than 90%.  Empiracally this suggests 90% is the threshold.  You state that it's anything above 0, can you provide documentation or code where this is stated?

Comment: The example that I've linked is to show that the API will return an empty "celebrities" JSON array if the confidence level is under 0, thus no confidence, and yes, it is stated that "Confidence score, between 0 and 1" in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtocallvisionapi